# Maytag dryer not heating

Tags: electrical, heating, dryer, washer, thermal

Can the thermal cut off if not working cause a new outlet thermistor to fail when connecting the machine (I didn’t check it prior to installing the thermistor)

Comment: what's an `outlet thermistor`?

Comment: What do you mean the thermal cut off not working?  Does it stay open and the machine does not heat up or will not open if it gets too hot.

Comment: Have you checked the heating element? Is the dryer heating on timed dry but not on temperature sensor mode?

Comment: @jsotola apparently the outlet control thermistor reads exhaust air temps.